# How many candidates are usually invited for a campus interview?

Tags: job-search, interview

I am currently a candidate for a few jobs, and have a few campus interviews.

**How many candidates are typically invited for a campus interview?**

I am mostly interested in answers for positions for the range of positions, tenure-track, non-tenure track, lecturer positions, and postdocs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For tenure-track positions my department generally invites 3 candidates for on-site interviews after doing phone screenings. This is what I have seen from a lot of universities in the US.

Other types of positions don't have standard rules. Non-tenure track and adjuct positions are filled as needed, don't involve as rigorous of interviews, and may never be brought on-site. Postdocs are usually hired by the individual PI rather than the department.

Comment: I'm in a math department with similar policies.  We typically bring in 3 tenure track candidates for an on-campus interview (after a round of screening interviews by Skype.)  For a one year visiting assistant professor position or even a permanent lecturer position we'd typically hire based on Skype interviews without any on-campus interview unless the candidate happened to be close enough to drive to campus for an interview.

Comment: For math tenure track, I've seen 3-6 for 1 position, and maybe 5-8 for 2 positions.